# Filtering subjects with NOT(-)

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want to filter every message that is sent to a mailing list, except those that begin (or just contain) "Re:"

In "Has the words" I've put.

```
subject:(mailing-list) subject:(-re)
```

However that will seem to pull out (archive) entire threaded messages where the first one is not a "Re:" But the responses are.

I basically just want replies to go to my mail mailbox, but archive the rest.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You only want one `subject:` field:

```
subject:("mailing-list" -re)
```

Gmail can only deal with one of each field operator.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the not operator on subject: instead?

> subject:(mailing-list) -subject:(re)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either.